# Intent to play video on Android from file on SD Card

Tags: android, file, video, android-intent, uri

I'm trying to load an intent to play a video file on my phone's SD drive. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong...

```
String movieurl = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Videos/Wildlife.wmv";

Intent intentToPlayVideo = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intentToPlayVideo.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(movieurl), "video/*");
startActivity(intentToPlayVideo);
```

I get an error "File cannot be displayed of played".

Any thoughts?

Note:
I've also tried:

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.setDataSource(movieurl);
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

Which fails with exception: java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1

Comment: can you debug your movieurl?  just log.d it?  it might have an extra file separator or something

Comment: Yes, I can, it shows up as:
"/mnt/sdcard/Videos/Wildlife.wmv"

Comment: @J J: Just a shot in the dark but could it be a case-sensitivity issue? In other words is the 'Videos' directory spelled with that exact case? Also 'Wildlife.wmv'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out...

Turns out that on the Droid X2, `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() returns "/mnt/sdcard"`, which isn't actually the SD Card.

(Found this out by doing a `File.listFiles()`)

The actual SD Card directory on the Droid X2 is `"/mnt/sdcard-ext".`

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I find this troubling (I'm not doubting you, its just troubling).  The whole point of Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() is that you retrieve the path to the SD card, no matter the device.  The fact that it provides an incorrect path makes me worry about the integrity of that method.

Comment: Yeah, I completely agree... Especially since the path that gets returned implies that it is the sdcard!

More info here: http://androidforums.com/motorola-droid-x2/339485-mnt-sdcard-vs-mnt-sdcard-ext.html

Comment: @John @J J - This is a quote from the docs for `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`...Note: don't be confused by the word "external" here. This directory can better be thought as media/shared storage. It is a filesystem that can hold a relatively large amount of data and that is shared across all applications (does not enforce permissions). Traditionally this is an SD card, but it may also be implemented as built-in storage in a device that is distinct from the protected internal storage and can be mounted as a filesystem on a computer. (See follow on comment also)...

Comment: "In devices with multiple "external" storage directories (such as both secure app storage and mountable shared storage), this directory represents the "primary" external storage that the user will interact with." See "http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()" - it's well documented.

Comment: Thanks for following up on that.  If it's documented, I suppose there's less to worry about.  Good research!

Comment: OK, so how do we get the SD Card path for sure, since Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() seems to be kind of unreliable? I am trying to write a file on SD card and it's giving IO Exception, as Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() returns /mnt/sdcard/ but in actual it should be /mnt/sdcard-ext/

Answer (score 1):

Does the WMV file play by itself in the standard media player? I'd suspect if you continue to get errors that perhaps the file is just not playable.

Comment: Yes, it does. I went to Files>>SD Card>>Videos and clicked on the file there and it played normally.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(movieurl));
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fis.getFD());
fis.close();
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```